Build services with Docker in GitHub Actions, and try to run the integration tests will get socket hang up
When I build the service with Docker locally, I can test it using Postman CLI with the address 127.0.0.1.
However, when I push my code to GitHub and then run docker compose up -d in GitHub Actions, I confirm that all services are running. But when I run Postman CLI in GitHub Actions, I get a "socket hang up" error:
  POST 127.0.0.1:3000/send-otp [errored]
     socket hang up
  2. Response status code is 200

Here some part of my .workflow yml:
jobs:
  build_for_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:      
    - name: Start service docker
    run: |
      docker compose up -d
      sleep 10
      docker ps

    - name: Run postman tests
    run: |
      curl -o- "https://dl-cli.pstmn.io/install/linux64.sh" | sh #Install postman CLI
      postman login --with-api-key key
      postman collection run collection-id -e env-id


I also tried using curl with the addresses 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, and localhost (with the service running on port 3000):
Run curl 127.0.0.1:3000 || curl 0.0.0.0:3000 || curl localhost:3000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Error: Process completed with exit code 52.

Seems 127.0.0.1:3000 get Connection reset by peer.
Here is the output of netstat -lt:
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
.
.
.
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3015            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN <-- Port 3000 is here    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:redis           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mysql           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3456            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:4566               [::]:*                  LISTEN 

Is there a way to access localhost from Docker in GitHub Actions?
